# Getting min from GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I have the following table `course`

```
course(idcourse, title, description, price, date, instructor)
```

And I want to get the instructor with less courses. So far I can get each instructor with the number of courses he teaches

```
SELECT instructor, count(*)
FROM courses
GROUP BY instructor;
```

The result of this query in my example is this one:

```
INSTRUCTOR COUNT(*)
1          5
2          2
7          5
```

Now I need to get the instructor with less courses. Which is this particular case is `2`.

I have tried using `HAVING count(*) = min(*)` but it gives a syntax error.

How should I get the min? Should I try a different approach?

Comment: What is the database?

Comment: What if there are two instructors who have the same number of courses and are both at the `min`?  For example, with your sample data if you wanted the instructor with the `max` then both 1 and 7 have 5 courses.  There might be multiple results in contrast to "the instructor with less courses".

Comment: It's okay if the SELECT stament returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `having` like that (at least with Oracle) :

```
    SELECT instructor, count(*) cnt
    FROM courses
    GROUP BY instructor
    HAVING count(*) = (select min(count(*)) from courses group by instructor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` ([SQL:2008 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause)):

```
SELECT instructor, count(*)
FROM courses
GROUP BY instructor
ORDER BY 2 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Some databases do not yet support this syntax, but have alternative syntax like `LIMIT 1`. Some others support `TOP 1` like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 instructor, count(*)
FROM courses
GROUP BY instructor
ORDER BY 2
```

See extensive list of more alternative syntaxes in the earlier referenced [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#FETCH_FIRST_clause).

NB: The `ORDER BY 2` clause will order the results by the second column (ascending), after which the `FETCH FIRST` (or alternative) clause reduces the result to just the first record.